# Issues with autofs "problem reading master map, maximum wait exceeded"

Tags: automounting, cifs, autofs

I am trying to mount a cifs partition using autofs. After a lot of trial and errors, I finally manage to get it mounted (the main issue I ran into is that in the instructions, [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autofs), this line in the mapping file

```
"[any_name] -fstype=cifs,[other_options] > ://[remote_server]/[remote_share_name]"
```

should really be:

```
"[remote_share_name] -fstype=cifs,[other_options] ://[remote_server]/"
```

At any rate after all this, I am able to mount my cifs partition using this command:

```
sudo automount -f -d &
```

Unfortunately, when I use the actual autofs service using the command below, my share does not get mounted

```
sudo /sbin/service autofs restart
```

I looked at the log files using after configuring autofs sysconfig to be in debug mode, and see the following errors:

> Dec 18 13:33:51 SRVR_XYZ automount[7986]: autofs stopped
>   Dec 18 13:46:09 SRVR_XYZ automount[8740]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): could not open master map file /etc/auto.master
>   Dec 18 13:46:09 SRVR_XYZ automount[8740]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): could not open master map file /etc/auto.master
>   Dec 18 13:46:11 SRVR_XYZ automount[8740]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): could not open master map file /etc/auto.master
>   Dec 18 13:46:13 SRVR_XYZ automount[8740]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): could not open master map file /etc/auto.master
>   Dec 18 13:46:15 SRVR_XYZ automount[8740]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): could not open master map file /etc/auto.master
>   Dec 18 13:46:17 SRVR_XYZ automount[8740]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): could not open master map file /etc/auto.master
>   Dec 18 13:46:19 SRVR_XYZ automount[8740]: problem reading master map, maximum wait exceeded
>   Dec 18 13:46:19 SRVR_XYZ automount[8740]: automount: warning: could not read at least one map source after waiting, continuing ...
>   Dec 18 13:46:19 SRVR_XYZ automount[8740]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): could not open master map file /etc/auto.master
>   Dec 18 13:53:34 SRVR_XYZ automount[9139]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): could not open master map file /etc/auto.master
>   Dec 18 13:53:34 SRVR_XYZ automount[9139]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): could not open master map file /etc/auto.master
>   Dec 18 13:53:36 SRVR_XYZ automount[9139]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): could not open master map file /etc/auto.master
>   Dec 18 13:53:38 SRVR_XYZ automount[9139]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): could not open master map file /etc/auto.master
>   Dec 18 13:53:40 SRVR_XYZ automount[9139]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): could not open master map file /etc/auto.master
>   Dec 18 13:53:42 SRVR_XYZ automount[9139]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): could not open master map file /etc/auto.master
>   Dec 18 13:53:44 SRVR_XYZ automount[9139]: problem reading master map, maximum wait exceeded
>   Dec 18 13:53:44 SRVR_XYZ automount[9139]: automount: warning: could not read at least one map source after waiting, continuing ...
>   Dec 18 13:53:44 SRVR_XYZ automount[9139]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): could not open master map file /etc/auto.master
>   Dec 18 13:54:18 SRVR_XYZ automount[9250]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): could not open master map file /etc/auto.master
>   Dec 18 13:54:18 SRVR_XYZ automount[9250]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): could not open master map file /etc/auto.master
>   Dec 18 13:54:20 SRVR_XYZ automount[9250]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): could not open master map file /etc/auto.master
>   Dec 18 13:54:22 SRVR_XYZ automount[9250]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): could not open master map file /etc/auto.master
>   Dec 18 13:54:24 SRVR_XYZ automount[9250]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): could not open master map file /etc/auto.master
>   Dec 18 13:54:26 SRVR_XYZ automount[9250]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): could not open master map file /etc/auto.master
>   Dec 18 13:54:28 SRVR_XYZ automount[9250]: problem reading master map, maximum wait exceeded
>   Dec 18 13:54:28 SRVR_XYZ automount[9250]: automount: warning: could not read at least one map source after waiting, continuing ...
>   Dec 18 13:54:28 SRVR_XYZ automount[9250]: lookup_read_master: lookup(file): could not open master map file /etc/auto.master

I have no idea why this is I made sure to set the proper permissions (chmod 640) and ownership of /etc/auto.master to the root account.

I have no idea why autofs service cannot mount the partition, while it works properly when I manually launch automout.

I use:

> Automount version 5.0.5-133.el6_9
>   Linux distro: CentOS release 6.9(Final)

Here is how the /etc/auto.master file looks like:

```
#
# Sample auto.master file
# This is a 'master' automounter map and it has the following format:
# mount-point [map-type[,format]:]map [options]
# For details of the format look at auto.master(5).
#
/misc   /etc/auto.misc
#
# NOTE: mounts done from a hosts map will be mounted with the
#       "nosuid" and "nodev" options unless the "suid" and "dev"
#       options are explicitly given.
#
/net    -hosts
#
# Include central master map if it can be found using
# nsswitch sources.
#
# Note that if there are entries for /net or /misc (as
# above) in the included master map any keys that are the
# same will not be seen as the first read key seen takes
# precedence.
#
+auto.master
/mnt/cifs /etc/auto.cifs-shares --ghost
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

AutoFS uses a two-level hierarchy of configuration files.

1. **Top-level control `/etc/auto.master`**

   The top-most file in the hierarchy is `/etc/auto.master` and it defines the directory trees over which AutoFS has control. Your example file in your question had three non-comment lines:

   ```
   /misc   /etc/auto.misc
   /net    -hosts
   +auto.master
   ```

   This says that /misc is to be managed through AutoFS by the file or script `/etc/auto.misc`, and that `/net` is to be derived from the set of "Known hosts running NFS". The final line says that NIS should be consulted for a central map. You will not be running NIS so that line is irrelevant.

   I would suggest that you comment out the `/net` and the `+auto.master` lines leaving just the `/misc /etc/auto.misc` definition.
2. **Second level implementation**

   Now we have only one file remaining for the second level of the hierarchy, `/etc/auto.misc`. We can edit that to include your new definition:

   ```
   [share_name] -fstype=cifs,[other_options] ://[remote_server]/[remote_share]"
   ```

   For example, this entry will create a transient entry `/misc/myshare` that maps directly to the share `//CIFSSERVER/ITSSHARE`:

   ```
   myshare -fstype=cifs,noperm,credentials=/root/.cifscred ://cifsserver/itsshare
   ```

   Note that until the share is accessed by explicit name it will not appear in `/misc`. You can see errors reported in the logger (`/var/log/syslog` on my version of Debian, for example).

---

Personally I like to rename `/misc` as `/var/autofs/misc` in `/etc/auto.master` so that it's not in the way, and create a top level directory `/autofs` with symlinks to the known entries in `/var/autofs/misc`. In my example's case,

```
# Prepare the /etc/auto.master file
#
mkdir -p -m755 /var/autofs/misc /autofs
rmdir /misc
sed -i.bak 's!^/misc!/var/autofs/misc!' /etc/auto.master

# Create the symlink
#
cd /autofs
ln -s ../var/autofs/misc/myshare
```

and I would then reference AutoFS mounts in `/autofs`. You may find this doesn't work for you, especially if AutoFS-mounting filesystems is a slow/expensive process, but it saves me having to remember all the AutoFS mount names.