# How can I get a non-blocking network file share between windows and linux PCs

Tags: samba, nfs, freeze, file-sharing

I have a file share server (samba daemon) running on a Debian server at a local network. My never-ending problem is that whenever I leave the local network (take my notebook to work, or outside) my Ubuntu system freezes. Investigation shows gnome-shell and nautilus stuck in **D state**. This happens due to kernel not being able to access to the server (since I am not in the network anymore). Apparently, these processes can't be recovered without giving access to the server. Sometimes, this is not possible at all. In the past, I needed to force-reboot the system. With newer kernels, I can at least kill them.

**What I would like to have, is to have access to file share automatically, whenever I am in the network. And whenever I leave local network, my system shouldn't freeze. I don't want to manually mount/unmount the file server each time I leave network. I want to simply access the shares whenever possible and a simple error message if they are not accessible.**

The other Windows PC can do this and also required access.

Do I need to switch to **NFS**? Another protocol? A mount parameter? (I tried *nointr* and *soft* parameters)

My current mount line in **/etc/fstab**:

```
//server/media  /media/networkshare  cifs soft,credentials=/home/user/.credentials,iocharset=utf8,uid=useruid,vers=3.0 0  0
```

**autofs** is also blocking gnome-shell and other applications, if I leave the network before idle time. Or for some reason some application keeps accessing the network drive (such as nautilus or gnome-shell).

If I connect via **bookmarks in nemo** (Connect to server), this time gnome-shell or nemo won't enter D state but gnome-shell freezes when PC wakes up (sleep/wake up) in a new network (different local network, without access to file servers).

This has nothing to do with [Issues with autofs "problem reading master map, maximum wait exceeded"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411531)

Comment: My suggestion would that you remove the entry from `/etc/fstab`, because that file declares the filesystems that must be mounted at boot. Instead, [move across to the automounter (autofs)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/424160/100397), which mounts filesystems "on demand".

Comment: I tried that now and it seems to be better in terms of automatically mounting the shares.  However, if I lose the connection before the timeout, my system freezes like before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issues with autofs "problem reading master map, maximum wait exceeded"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411531/issues-with-autofs-problem-reading-master-map-maximum-wait-exceeded)

Comment: @MrShunz, it has nothing to do with the linked question. Not even remotely.